# Will you merge update-manager into Software Center?

Tags: software-center

this could be good to see in Oneiric

Answer (score 3):

To suggest this idea, post it on the [Ubuntu Brainstorm site](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/), where you can suggest ideas for Ubuntu.

More on how it works [here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/tour/).